# Where is my ComboBox located

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, userform, multipage

So, I am doing this app. And I have implemented a multipage in my userform. Now I have around 120 comboboxes distributed in 6 pages. So what I need is that I need a procedure that I can use to store in a string the name of the page where a specific ComboBox is located in. Does anyone know how I could do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
Debug.Print Me.ComboBox1.Parent.Name
Debug.Print Me.Controls("ComboBox1").Parent.Name
```